# Reference a list of objects in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Say I have a two objects, `a` and `b`, and a function `f1` in R

```
a<- 5
b<- 10

f1<-function(){
    out<- a+b
    return(out)
```

I want to write a for loop that evaluates the sensitivity of this function to the values of `a` and `b` by changing them each and running the function again. I imagine creating a vector of the objects and then running some code like this:

```
params<- c(a,b)
for(i in params){
    store<- i           #save the initial value of the object so I can restore it later.
    base<-f1()          #save function output with original object value
    i<- i*1.1           #increase object value by 10%
    base.10<- f1()      #recalculate and save function output with new object value
    calc<- base.10/base #generate a response metric
    i<- store           #reset the object value to its original value
    return(calc)    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a function `f1` that relies on objects `a` and `b` (which are not defined in that function), and you want to test the sensitivity of its output to values of `a` and `b`. One way to approach this would be looping through the values you want for the sensitivity analysis and manipulating the parent environment of `f1` so it uses these values:

```
f1 <- function() a + b
sensitivity <- function(params) {
  old.f1.env <- environment(f1)
  grid <- expand.grid(lapply(params, function(x) x * c(1, 1.1)))
  grid$outcome <- apply(grid, 1, function(x) {
    for (n in names(x)) {
      assign(n, x[n])
    }
    environment(f1) <- environment()
    ret <- f1()
    environment(f1) <- old.f1.env
    ret
  })
  grid
}
sensitivity(list(a=5, b=10))
#     a  b outcome
# 1 5.0 10    15.0
# 2 5.5 10    15.5
# 3 5.0 11    16.0
# 4 5.5 11    16.5
```

Here, we've performed computed the function value for a grid of `a` and `b` values, both at the original `a` and `b` value and at a 10% increased value.

Note that a lot of our work came from specifying the variables in the parent environment of `f1`. I would encourage you to restructure your code so your function `f1` takes the relevant parameters as input. Then you could use:

```
f1 <- function(a, b) a + b
sensitivity <- function(params) {
  grid <- expand.grid(lapply(params, function(x) x * c(1, 1.1)))
  grid$outcome <- apply(grid, 1, function(x) do.call(f1, as.list(x)))
  grid
}
sensitivity(list(a=5, b=10))
#     a  b outcome
# 1 5.0 10    15.0
# 2 5.5 10    15.5
# 3 5.0 11    16.0
# 4 5.5 11    16.5
```

Comment: This would work, but I really want to define the range of values in the context of the current object values. I want variable a and variable b to go up 10%> This is because in my real function I have many different variables, whose values are on very different orders of magnitude, so I can't specify a common set of values for all of them to take on.

Comment: @colin OK, I've updated when I pass to the `sensitivity` function to process both the base value and 10% more than the base value.

Comment: This is so close. Is there any way to feed this command a vector of objects, instead of changing the function everytime I add/remove a parameter? I'd like to be able to plug and play this code to other models I run, and just feed it a vector of parameters I want to estimate the sensitivity to, and those parameters will always be set as R objects.

Comment: @colin do you mean you want to pass it the names of the variables?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean objects. I have models that are based on parameters, which I specify with names like a-z, and they are each R objects that are specified before the model runs. The model is just an R function that iterates through "time". I want to feed a sensitivity function a list of R objects (the model parameters), and have the function alter the parameters by ~10% to estimate some sensitivity parameters.

Comment: @colin OK, I've updated to handle what I think you're asking for, and I've also suggested a way to simplify the code (make `f1` take the relevant parameters as arguments).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect use case for closures.

```
get_f1 <- function(a, b) {
    f1<-function(){
        out<- a+b
        return(out)
    }
    return(f1)
}
```

Then:

```
my_f1 <- get_f1(a=5, b=10)
my_f1() #uses a=5 and b=10 because they are defined in the envir associated with my_f1
```

So in your loop you could simply do:

```
base <- (get_f1(a, b))()
base.10 <- (get_f1(a*1.1, b*1.1))()
```

Obviously you could define `get_f1` with arguments `i=c(a, b)`.

Use a closure (function attached to an environment) rather than tinkering with environments!

tl;dr: closures are awesome

Answer (score 1):

Reading some of your comments, I think this is actually what you want: `sensitivity` takes a function and a list of arguments and returns the sensitivity of the function to its arguments. (BTW what you call sensitivity, already means [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity))

```
sensitivity <- function(fun, args) {
    out <- lapply(names(args), function(cur) { 
        base10 <- do.call(fun, `[[<-`(args, cur, `[[`(args,cur)*1.1))
        base10 / do.call(fun, args)
    })
    names(out) <- names(args)
    return(out)
}
```

Example:

```
f1 <- function(a,b) a+b
a1 <- list(a=5, b=2)
sensitivity(f1, a1)
```

This gives

```
$a
[1] 1.03

$b
[1] 1.07
```

Example 2:

```
f2 <- function(x, y, z) x^2 +3*y*z
sensitivity(f2, list(x=1, y=2, z=3))


$x
[1] 1.011053

$y
[1] 1.094737

$z
[1] 1.094737
```

It works "plug-and-play" with any function, BUT it requires you to define f differently (one would say, correctly). I *could* write something that would work with your function f as it is written but it would be much work and bad taste. If you want code modularity, you just cannot use side effects...

PS: if you would prefer to have a vector returned instead of a list, simply change `lapply` to `sapply` in the definition of `sensitivity`.

This would give for the last example:

```
> sensitivity(f2, list(x=1, y=2, z=3))
       x        y        z 
1.011053 1.094737 1.094737
```

PPS: any reason why you are not computing the gradient of f rather than doing what you are doing?

Comment: can you explain more about why my function is written "incorrectly", and why how you have specified it is correct?

Comment: If your function make use of a and b in a way as simple as your example, I do not understand what is the benefit of not passing a and b as parameters of f, especially given that scoping with R may be really unintuitive. I must say that I find particularly unappealing the fact that calling f at different times with the same arguments may yield different results. It is error prone for no good reason. And it makes it hard to simple things like what you want to do.  It is not incorrect, but I think it is inferior.

Comment: If you want to perfor; f on `x` and `y`, you currently have to do `a<-x` and `b<-y` then `f()`, instead of `f(x,y)`. Don't you find it ugly? To be fair, I do often use external variable in my functions, but only because they are actually fixed values or values that I very rarely change, hence hardly "parameters". Given that you are studying the sensitivity of f to a and b, I can only assume that a and b are important parameters of f and thus should be explicitly passed for convenience and modularity.